# Jenkins-X 3 operator install fails to download "jx3/jx-git-operator"

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, jenkins-x-3

Trying to successfully install Jenkins X 3 on a vanilla Kubernetes cluster.
Installing jenkins-x 3 operator in AWS EKS vanilla cluster, using the following command:

```
jx admin operator --username myuser --token PAT -u https://gitlab.mydomain.com/jenkins-x-admin
```

The output returns some successful queries to my Gitlab repository, and then fails with the error output: "'Error: failed to download "jx3/jx-git-operator"'"

Full console output:

```
git clone URL is https://gitlab.gps-garage-pak.com/admins/jenkins-x-admin
now verifying we have a valid git username and token so that we can clone the git repository inside kubernetes...
git username is adgantt for URL https://gitlab.gps-garage-pak.com/admins/jenkins-x-admin and we have a valid password
running command:

/Users/me/.jx3/plugins/bin/helm-3.6.2 upgrade --install \
    --set url=https://gitlab.mydomain.com/jenkins-x-admin \
    --set username=myuser \
    --set password=**** --namespace jx-git-operator --create-namespace jxgo jx3/jx-git-operator

error: failed to run command /Users/me/.jx3/plugins/bin/helm-3.6.2 upgrade --install \
    --set url=https://gitlab.mydomain.com/jenkins-x-admin \
    --set username=myuser \
    --set password=**** --namespace jx-git-operator --create-namespace jxgo jx3/jx-git-operator: failed to run '/Users/me/.jx3/plugins/bin/helm-3.6.2 upgrade --install --set url=https://gitlab.mydomain.com/jenkins-x-admin --set username=myuser --set password=***** jx-git-operator --create-namespace jxgo jx3/jx-git-operator' command in directory '', output: 'Error: failed to download "jx3/jx-git-operator" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to firt add the repo to helm list

```
helm repo add jx3 https://storage.googleapis.com/jenkinsxio/charts

helm repo update
```

Run the helm command as you are running

```
helm upgrade --install \
    --set url=$GIT_URL \
    --set username=$GIT_USER \
    --set password=$GIT_TOKEN \
     jx-git-operator --create-namespace jxgo jx3/jx-git-operator
```

Undercover `jx admin operator`  calling same helm command and option.

**Option 2**

Clone repo locally

```
git clone https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx-git-operator
```

go inside the folder

```
cd jx-git-operator/charts/jx-git-operator
```

now you can run the helm directly here

```
helm upgrade --install \
        --set url=$GIT_URL \
        --set username=$GIT_USER \
        --set password=$GIT_TOKEN \
         jx-git-operator --create-namespace jxgo ./ #this mean you are in existing directory
```